# How to search an arraylist to find duplicate values while ignoring some strings

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I add to my arraylist a datatype and a function name ex. int "func", but everytime I want to add it to the list, I also want to check if that "func" already exists ignoring the "int" because many functions can have the same datatype but cant have the same name. How would I solve this using Arraylist java

IDs would be "func" for example
d.func is my arraylist of function names

```
        String IDs = tokM1(E).getToken();
        String IDs2 = tokM2(E).getToken();
        d.func.add(IDs);
        d.func.add(IDs2);
        for (int i=0; i> d.func.size();){
            //search array to find duplicates of IDs ignoring IDs2(ex. int), if duplicates found then reject (reject method written)
        //reject();
        }
```

Would expect it to reject if duplicate values found for IDs found but ignore datatype (IDs2)

Answer (score 0):

If I interprete correctly, you add the function name first to your arrayList, and then the datatype to the same arrayList. If this is the case, you could check the arrayList for the IDs before you add them to the arrayList. You could make the for-loop to traverse every 2nd element starting with index 0:

```
    String IDs = tokM1(E).getToken();
    String IDs2 = tokM2(E).getToken();
    boolean isDuplicate = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.func.size(); i = i+2) {
      if(d.func.get(i).contentEquals(IDs)) {
         isDuplicate = true;
         break;
      }
    }
    if (!isDuplicate) {
      d.func.add(IDs);
      d.func.add(IDs2);
    }
```